# UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating() at second time doesn't work when in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show UIActivityIndicatorView before sending request and hide when request is ending every time.

So I put the request code in `viewWillAppear()`.
First time, It's OK, `UIActivityIndicatorView` startAnimating and shows before requesting, and `stopAnimation` and hides after requesting.

However, the second time, that is, back from another `viewController`**(whether from vc in tab or pushed by navigationController)**, `UIActivityIndicatorView` shows but doesn't hide, the code is executed the same as the first time, include breakpoint.

`StopAnimation()` is exactly executed but activityIndicatorView doesn't stop or hide.

I try to put the request code in `viewDidAppear()`.
`ActivityIndicatorView` will stop and hide whenever back from another `viewController`.

Does UIActivityIndicatorView work special?

```
    /* Has problem
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        request()
    }
    */

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        request()
    }

    private func request() {

        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
            data, response, error in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
            }
        }

        // 9.20 edited
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: on the second time, does it not appear? or does it not hide?

Comment: Hides When Stopped is checked OR set to TRUE ?

Comment: Your code is missing task.resume()

Comment: @arvidurs on the second time, it shows but doesn't hide...

Comment: @KrunalDarji it is always using default setting of TRUE~~~

Comment: @PavelKozlov It's my question's miss, and I added it today..thanks~~